# Need to Identify PhoneNumber by Category for CustomerIDs OR by Rank

Tags: postgresql

I've been trying to figure this one out for the last few days but still have been unsuccessful.  I've tried to find the answer, but not sure if I'm phrasing the question correctly, so I'm hoping if I pose it here in the hopes that one of you fine people will be able to help!

I have a table in my PostGres Db that houses all of our customer phone numbers by customer ID and type (IE Home, Work, Cell, Day, Evening, etc...).  I need to pull those phone numbers and put them into 1 of three columns called home_phone, work_phone, or cell_phone based on the type column.  I figured "easy! I'll just use a case statement!", but the problem I ran into is that the type column is freeform and my final query needs to be automated, so I can't be constantly updating my case statements to add any new 'random' type that may come in, and there's also no guarantee that a customer will have a phone number that fits into any of the three categories.

I somehow need to be able to drop a phone number into my final home/work/cell columns, and categorize them appropriately if I have the correct 'type', BUT if I don't have the correct 'type' then I still need to get those phone numbers into 1 of the three columns.

I tried to figure out something based on RANK() that would basically work like this: IF(type = 'home' then phone_number ELSE SELECT phone_number where RANK() = MAX(RANK())) AS home_phone, IF(type = 'cell' then phone_number ELSE SELECT phone_number where RANK() = MAX(RANK())-1) AS cell_phone, etc...

But I couldn't get anywhere with that, and honestly I don't even think it's correct and is taking me down the wrong path.

It's probably relevant to say that I have read-only access as well.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

My current code:

```
select customer_id
,string_agg(home_phone,'|' order by customer_id) as home_phone
,string_agg(cell_phone,'|' order by customer_id) as cell_phone
,string_agg(work_phone,'|' order by customer_id) as work_phone
from(
select 
customer_id
,case when type in ('Home', 'phone') then phone_number end as home_phone
,case when type in ('cellphone', 'Cell', 'Mobile') then phone_number end as cell_phone
,case when type in ('Work') then phone_number end as work_phone
from reporting_data.lead_customer_phone_number
order by customer_id
) zzz
group by customer_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

accomplished this with a series of CASE statements. Code below in case anyone runs into a similar problem.

```
select lcph.customer_id,
              case 
                     when (phones.home_phone is not null) then phones.home_phone
                     when (phones.Other_1 is not null) then phones.Other_1
                     when (phones.Other_2 is not null) then phones.Other_2      --should never occur
                     when (phones.Other_3 is not null) then phones.Other_3      --should never occur
              end as home_phone,

              case 
                     when (phones.cell_phone is not null) then phones.cell_phone
                     when (phones.cell_phone is null and phones.home_phone is not null and phones.Other_1 is not null) then phones.Other_1
                     when (phones.Other_2 is not null) then phones.Other_2
                     when (phones.Other_3 is not null) then phones.Other_3      --should never occur
              end as cell_phone,

              case 
                     when (phones.work_phone is not null) then phones.work_phone
                     when (phones.work_phone is null and phones.home_phone is not null and phones.cell_phone is not null and phones.Other_1 is not null) then phones.Other_1
                     when (phones.work_phone is null and (phones.home_phone is not null or phones.cell_phone is not null) and phones.Other_2 is not null) then phones.Other_2
                     when (phones.Other_3 is not null) then phones.Other_3
              end as work_phone

  from reporting_data.lead_customer_phone_number lcph
  left join (
              -- simulate a pivot to create a row of phone numbers for each customer id
              select customer_id,
                           MAX(home_phone) as home_phone,
                           MAX(cell_phone) as cell_phone,
                           MAX(work_phone) as work_phone,
                           MAX(Other_1) as Other_1,
                           MAX(Other_2) as Other_2,
                           MAX(Other_3) as Other_3
              from (
                     -- extract out just the phone numbers we want to use
                     select a.customer_id,
                                  case when (phonetype='HOME' and level=1) then a.parsephone end as home_phone,
                                  case when (phonetype='CELL' and level=1) then a.parsephone end as cell_phone,
                                  case when (phonetype='WORK' and level=1) then a.parsephone end as work_phone,
                                  case when (phonetype='OTHER' and a.level = 1) then a.parsephone end as Other_1,
                                  case when (phonetype='OTHER' and a.level = 2) then a.parsephone end as Other_2,
                                  case when (phonetype='OTHER' and a.level = 3) then a.parsephone end as Other_3  
                     from (
                           -- Take all the lead phone numbers and group and number within the groups
                           select customer_id,
                                         phonetype,
                                         parsephone,
                                         row_number() over (partition by customer_id, phonetype  order by parsephone) as Level 
                           from (
                                  -- because duplicate data was found, filter out the dups first
                                  select distinct     customer_id,
                                                              case upper(type)
                                                                     when 'HOME' then 'HOME'
                                                                     when 'PHONE' then 'HOME'
                                                                     when 'CELLPHONE' then 'CELL'
                                                                     when 'CELL' then 'CELL'
                                                                     when 'MOBILE' then 'CELL'
                                                                     when 'WORK' then 'WORK'
                                                                     else 'OTHER'
                                                              end as phonetype,
                                                              regexp_replace(phone_number, '[^0-9]*', '', 'g') as parsephone,
                                                              phone_number as rawphone
                                                  from reporting_data.lead_customer_phone_number  
                                  ) ph
                           ) a
                     ) b
              group by customer_id
              ) phones on lcph.customer_id=phones.customer_id
```